# I cant install and run my android app. AVD doesnt boot, it stucks on Android boot logo.(Im using Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Android Studio shows this when uploading the because the System isnt running, but how can I get it running?
I cant press any buttons of the avd or anything like this. Ive already created new avds with more RAM and tried running the app several times.
I think the avd should normally boot, show homescreen and run the app, but that doesnt work. After having pressed run, the "Choosing Device" Window shows in the "Compatible" column: "No, minSDK(API 16)> deviceSDK(API 1)". But I configured everything for API 22.
Tell me if you need my code or further information about my AVD, versions...

```
Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\FamileScholl\AndroidStudioProjects\OwnGalaxy\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.familescholl.owngalaxy
```

Installing com.example.familescholl.owngalaxy
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.familescholl.owngalaxy"
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com) for overall better experience with emulating Android devices. And it will probably show your issue.

Comment: If I helped you please upvote and accept as answer! Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks, ill try it. But is there a way to solve the problem with android studio emulator?

Comment: The best you can do is just forget about it. Genymotion is faster, more like a real device, and also free!